# How can company show a profit before income tax, but then lose money after income tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, accounting, corporate-earnings

I am looking at a recent earnings release from Apache Oil. The symbol for Apache Oil is APA. Here is a link to the earnings release: [Earnings Release](https://investor.apacorp.com/static-files/fe3e6130-5977-4411-a7d0-46b343ed0996)

The release (on page 6) shows that the company had a profit before income tax but lost money after income tax. This means that it paid an income tax rate in excess of 100%. How could that be? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Income for tax purposes is calculated in a very specific way, based on local tax law, which very often differs from accounting standards, and often by large amounts.

Realistically, there are a whole host of reasons why tax income <> accounting income. Sometimes this is because tax law is written to be beneficial to certain industries (like allowing fast depreciation of tech assets, which has been pretty common the last 15 years in the US and Canada, in theory to encourage development). Sometimes tax law is punitive in certain circumstances [maybe intentionally, maybe not].

In this particular case, while the 'net income' line for accounting is washed out by tax impacts, you can see that other adjusting items bring things back at the end of the day so that annual total adjusted earnings is $541, whereas the tax on that is $169, which is a rate of  about 31% - pretty typical.

Why the tax hit dinged particularly hard on what's shown as the top-line earnings number, I don't know, would need to investigate much deeper into full-year statements to find out.